# Tags container overlapping tabs in user page

Tags: bug, profile-page

This is what I am talking about:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

This happens only when I am logged in (because otherwise the "track the next one" container won't appear).

The issue is consistent across all browsers.

I thought of adding a `margin-top` to the tabs container, but it seems that the contaiers above all have the same height, so the height of the overlapping container should be unified as well.